# How to disable Postgresql messages translation

Tags: postgresql, internationalization, jdbc

Is there a way to disable the Postgresql translation of messages? I´m running my appl and Postgresql on a pt_BR Windows machine and when a exception is thrown the error message is translated to Portuguese, like:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERRO: relação "unidade_federacao" não existe
>     Posição: 25

I would like the messages to appear in English.

I´m using the driver postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc3.jar on a Java (with Hibernate) app.

thanks in advance,
Fabrício Lemos

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could change lc_messages in postgresql.conf or just per database:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname SET lc_messages=en_us;
```

See also the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/locale.html).

Comment: Thank you Frank. I edited postgresql.conf changing lc_messages = 'Portuguese_Brazil.1252' to lc_messages=en_us. Now it works fine!

Answer (score 2):

Under Windows, some **psql** error messages are getting translated corresponding to the format setting in Windows settings -> Clock, Language, and Region -> Change location -> Formats -> Format.

To prevent a **mix of translated and untranslated messages**, I've set this format to "English (United States)".

Answer (score 0):

execute the following query to your database in order to find the postgres.conf file which is loaded for the configuration:

```
SHOW config_file;
```

Edit your *postgres.conf* file with your prefered lc.... *lc_messages,lc_numeric*...etc.

i think you can change all with lc_ALL
example :  lc_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

Finally execute the following command to reload conf.

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```